# Why are some YouTube API v3 VideoCategories listed as "assignable": false? How do I POST to VideoCategories listed as "assignable": false?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm unable to POST videos using YouTube's API v3 VideoCategories listed as "assignable": false.  I have been unable to find a means to work around this.  Is there a partnership level or different end point that will allow for access to these VideoCategories?

Answer (score 0):

Those with `assigned:false` are probably only available to those who use Youtube's Content Manager

> The features described in this article are available only to partners
>   who use YouTube's Content Manager to manage their copyrighted content.

More regarding that on this [link](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4594615?hl=en)